# How to decode memory chunk header in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, .net, mono, blazor, webassembly

I am invoking unmarshalled JS method from Blazor and passing byte array with UTF8 encoded string "testa" as method argument.
In JS I receive address pointer to access my argument and when I try to access that memory chunk I see that it starts with some header/prefix of 16bytes (88, -20, -68, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0) from which last 4 to int32 seems as payload length. What does the other header values represent?

[Here is example picture with payload bytes and unknown header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYu8v.png) "message" parameter is the intended string argument with value "testa" that I passed from C# side on  unmarshalled interop call. In JS end it came out like int which seems to be addres pointer to shared memory. In my case it is "114978712" and +20 is just to get chunk for unknown for me header(16bytes) + first 4 letters of payload (4bytes).

```
  public void Test()
    {
        var js = (WebAssemblyJSRuntime)Js;
        js.InvokeUnmarshalled<byte[], int>("BlazorExtensions.TestMarshalled", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testa"));
    }
```

Comment: "In JS I receive address pointer" sounds strange. Betrter explain it with some code samples.

Comment: @HenkHolterman There is shared memory reagion for JS and WASM which in this context is basicly byte array and address pointer is just index for array that points to beginning of memory reagion for your data. AFAIK.

Comment: C# objects (and arrays) have a prefix in memory. Is there an InvokeMarshalled ?

Comment: And you can verify that it is the payload length quickly by varying a little.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, I was testing unmarshalled invocation, so that prefix is comming from C# side? In this case I try to send only plain byte array which looks like intended on C# end.

Comment: It could be, I don't know for sure. It is about the right size. Details would have to come form the Mono runtime specs.

Comment: Sorry this isn't a proper answer but there are some js functions available from Blazor.platform that may help with this. You can see examples of them being used [Here](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile/blob/master/BlazorInputFile/wwwroot/inputfile.js#L50) in the readFileDataSharedMemory function.